# Uploading file to restful service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, upload

So i have this method in my CMSController (MVC Web Application):

```
[HttpPost]
public bool UploadFile(Stream file)
{
    return file != null;
}
```

and alongside that project, I created another console application for testing, and that one has 1 function, which looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Console.ReadLine();
    var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\test.txt", FileMode.Open);
    var file = new StreamContent(stream);


    var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    formData.Add(file, "file", "file");


    //"http://localhost:49200/api/users/currentUsers"
    string actionURL = "http://localhost:49200/api/cms/uploadFIle";
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, actionURL);
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
    request.Headers.Add("enctype", "application/octet-stream");
    request.Content = formData;


    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = client.SendAsync(request))
    {
        response.Wait();
        var resContent = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        resContent.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(resContent.Result);
        //Console.WriteLine(response.Result.RequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And I am always getting an error:

```
<Error>
<Message>The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Stream' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

I tried uploading image insted, using `request.Headers.Add("enctype", "image/jpeg");`, I tried (in CMSController.UploadFile) `public bool UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)`, I've tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135772/writing-a-rest-service-to-upload-a-file-in-c-sharp), I've tried editing the web config by adding the

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CMSController.UploadFIle" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="Streamed"
             sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483647"
                     maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                     maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                     maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                     maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

But I am always getting the same error (mentioned above).

How do you upload a file using Controller's function, and a console application?
 (If I didn't provide enough info, please comment below, I will explain/edit question/etc)

Comment: Tried setting the content type to application/octet-stream?

Comment: yes, like this `request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");` but then I get error that says "Content-Type" isn't a valid header